# samsung i9300 galaxy s3 corrupted

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, locked-out

my samsung mobile fell down and restarted. i noticed my screen wall paper getting changed. so i checked my about phone. it showed 4.1.1 android(previously  it was 4.4) i immediately checked my contacts and messages thinking it got flashed when it slipped my hands and fell down. everything seemed fine. so i took it easy. but  when i tried to unlock my phone later the pin is not working now. what to do now. i tried all my previous passwords also. it doesnot show password recovery  option to signin into gmail also. i tried resetting password through  samsungrecovery but it says sim has been changed. but the new sim was changed for morethan a month when i changed mobile network and the number is same so samsung recovery website is out of question for me now.

i donot wish to reset my phone as there are some mobile contacts saved in phone memory of my friends and no way of getting them from any others since i shifted to another city and some pics in phone memory.

someone plz suggest me what to do.

Comment: That sounds pretty strange: dropping a phone doesn't change the Android version. Have you rebooted the device already? Taken out the battery for a minute (if it has a removeable battery)? As for the lock, take a look at our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for a starter.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this, my LG Stylo got a corrupted file and I had to factory reset. Its a pain but you'll have to write everything down and put it all back in.